# How do I handle hashtags in regular expression for google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, hashtag

I have a URL goal I'm trying to track as a destination in google analytics.  Let's say its `https://foo.bar.com/#/home`.

Using "Equal to" I get nothing.   Using "Regular expression" When I type it in as a destination goal `foo.bar.com/#/home` I get nothing.

`./home` 22.31% conversion rate over last 7 days

`.#/home` 8.14% conversion rate

`.bar.com/#/home` 0 conversion rate

`.bar.com#/home` 8.14% conversion rate

`.foo.bar.com#/home` captures nothing

`foo` is dynamic so I only want the urls with both start with `foo` and have `.bar.com/#.home`.

Is there something about the `#` thats the issue?

***EDIT***

now i'm trying `foo\.bar.com/*/home` and I'm getting 8.5%.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hashes are not tracked in GA by default, so if you go to your real-time reports (or even just by analysing your `collect` hits via GA Debugger or dev tools), you'll see that whenever a hash appears in your page path, everything from the hash forward will be removed. This explains why you see 0% conversion rates for some of your attempts. You would have to send a virtual pageview instead and modify the destination url, so something like this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/vpv/new/destination/path');
```

And then in your goal destination, you can use the new path of `/vpv/new/destination/path`.

Comment: is this going to get incorrect results? ` foo\.bar.com/*/home`

Comment: I believe so because GA may discard everything after the `#`, so it might not see the `/home/` part which would cause a mismatch in your destination. You could do a quick experiment by installing GA Debugger, and then visiting that page, and then seeing what the `dp` value is.

Comment: Sorry, that should be the `dl` value, not `dp`.

Comment: This article http://online-metrics.com/regular-expressions/ suggests I can go with `.*`.  Do you agree?

Comment: No, I don't agree. So what's happening is that in your goal destination, if you are providing a (Regex) value of `foo\.bar\.com/.*/home`, this mean you are looking for anything like `foo.bar.com/blahblah/home` or `foo.bar.com/test/home`, etc. But because you have hashes in your URL, GA automatically ignores everything after the hash, so it only sees `foo.bar.com/` and nothing else. So this fails your goal destination match. Make sense? I think you just need to follow my suggestion to test in GA Debugger and inspect the `dp` parameter when you on a page with a hash in it.